# Swift Callback API assistance

Tags: swift

When calling  getItems function, XCode auto completes to:

```
getItems(success: (([File]) -> ())?, fail: ((Error) -> ())?)
```

I just need some assistance understanding what I need to input in order to get the list of items.

I've created simple callbacks and read up on Apple's closure documentation to better understand what's going on but am still a little confused by this in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to put `closure`s as parameters like below to use this function:

```
getItems(success: { (files) in
    // files: [File]
    for file in files {
        print(file)
    }
}, fail: { (error) in 
    // error: Error
    print(error)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! That did it.